# Can I get the ExecutablePath from a System.Management.EventArrivedEventArgs object?

Tags: c#, wql, executable-path

I'm using a System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher to get the process ID and executable path for a started process:

```
private void startWatcher_EventArrived(Object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    String processID = e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessID"].Value.ToString();

    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(new WqlObjectQuery(String.Format("Select ExecutablePath from Win32_Process where ProcessID = {0}", processID)));

    ManagementObject managementObject = null;
    foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
    {
        managementObject = obj;
        break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(managementObject["ExecutablePath"]);
}
```

Using this WQL Query:

> Select ExecutablePath from
>   Win32_ProcessStartTrace

Is there a way that I can avoid doing the object search, but still get the ExecutionPath, using what is already available in the EventArrivedEventArgs object?

All I really need is the ProcessID and the ExecuatblePath for each new process that starts up. Is this the simplest way to get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you got is as good as it gets.  The available properties are listed [here...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394374%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this article can help you: [Using WMI to monitor process creation, deletion and modification in .NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2006/02/11/438006.aspx)